# TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'init') in classifier.add

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am just having the following error in the input layer. I do have input data of 4 and the output of one. Additionally, I have one column string. The data is from a CSV file. Any help appreciated

```
classifier.add(Dense(1, init = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_shape = (4,)))

TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'init')
```

Comment: `kernel_initializer='random_uniform'` is what you are looking for I guess?

Comment: You use a recent version of Keras, but use an earlier Keras version syntax. Please study a recent Keras documentation e.g. the one techytushar proposed below.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://keras.io/layers/core/) there is no `init` argument in the Keras Dense layer, there are `kernel_initializer` and `bias_initializer` if you want to initialize any one of them.

Comment: classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)                                                   ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_10_input to have shape (11,) but got array with shape (83,). I am new and i am trying to understand the error can you please explain it to me thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell without looking at the whole NN architecture and the input shapes. You can edit the post to include this information This error happens when there is a mismatch in the shapes of the input data and input shape of neural network.

Answer (score 2):

Keras 1.2 doesn't support separate kernel/bias initializers, layers only take a single init parameter, eg, Dense(10, init="normal", activation="relu").
change it to Dense(10, activation="relu")