# TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'init') in keras.model

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am just having the following error whilst training a MNIST model(a CNN and FNN) using Keras. Complete beginner at machine learning BTW, so apologies if it is something obvious. Any help appreciated

```
def base_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(pixels, input_dim=pixels, init='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(num_op, init='normal', activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = base_model()
```

The above code then leads to TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'init')

The imports are as follows...

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.utils import np_utils

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

Comment: Looking at [the documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/) I don't see any `init` parameter, only `bias_initializer` and `kernel_initializer`. Maybe you are following a guide for an older version of keras? Try `kernel_initializer='normal'`

Comment: that was it! however now im getting tf is not defined error?

Comment: fixed it by import tensorflow as tf

Comment: look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59092788/typeerror-keyword-argument-not-understood-init-in-classifier-add